# Resources about the Javascript object model?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a good resource (comprehensive yet terse) that explains the Javascript object model: prototype, constructor, Function, Object, etc.

Surprisingly there aren't many resources out there that discuss this issue. The best I found, so far, is this: http://www.mollypages.org/misc/js.mp

Anyone familiar with other (hopefully better) explanations?

Comment: Note that that page includes `__proto__` and `constructor` which aren't available on all browsers and shouldn't be used. `constructor` in particular can be extremely misleading as to what it *really* does. Avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by Javascript object model, but if it's **inheritance** you're after, here's a [nice overview](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html) by Joost Diepenmaat, which includes few helpful diagrams. There's also a [decent article](http://www.3site.eu/doc/) on this subject by Andrea Giammarchi.

Answer (score 4):

I rate book "Javascript:The Good Parts" by douglas Crockford as one of the best for understanding Javascript model and its nuances.

Online you may find this helpful too.
http://kevlindev.com/tutorials/javascript/inheritance/index.htm
http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-prototype-property-in-javascript

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Crockford book is really good. 

Crockford also has some must read articles on javascript on his website. 
You get them starting from here: http://javascript.crockford.com/

Specific to your question are: "Private members in javascript", "Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript", "Classical Inheritance in JavaScript". 

I suggest you take a look also at the first article: "The World's Most Misunderstood Programming Language"

For me it was enlightening: put javascript into a different perspective

Answer (score 2):

[www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)

Comment: comprehensive but not terse. +1 though.